# Discord.py bot leaving voice channel

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've been making a discord bot which enters a vc plays an audio then leaves, but I can't seem to get the leaving part to work. Here is my code:

```
# Discord specific import
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="..")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def dan(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    channel = author.voice_channel
    vc = await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
    player = vc.create_ffmpeg_player('dan.mp3', after=lambda: print('done'))
    player.start()
    player.disconnect()

client.run('token')
```

I'm not getting any errors with this but at the same time the bot is not disconnecting from the vc and I have tried changing 'player' for 'client', 'Client' and 'client.voice'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problems were that:

1. I needed to use: await vc.disconnect()
2. My version of websockets was too high and needed to be below v4.0.0

Hope this helps people with my problem

Answer (score 0):

try `vc.disconnect()` as stated [here in the docs](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.disconnect), since `Client.join_voice_channel(channel)` [creates a `VoiceClient`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.join_voice_channel). Also I suggest not having redundant variables like

> `author = ctx.message.author`
>
> `channel = author.voice_channel`

When you can have `vc = await client.join_voice_channel(ctx.message.author.voice_channel)`

Also, another redundant variable is `Client = discord.Client()` since you don't use it anywhere, you use the `commands.Bot` instance, so it's best to remove that.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have worked, although I am not getting any errors the bot is still not disconnecting however the getting rid of redundant variables has worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`player.disconnect()` is a coroutine, you should use the `await` keyword before it.

```
await player.disconnect()
```