# Can't make Discord bot leave the voice channel in Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make my Discord bot leave the voice channel when someone types "leave" as a message, but I don't get any errors and the bot doesn't disconnect. Can someone help me?

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def leave(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    await server.disconnect()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py bot leaving voice channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139249/discord-py-bot-leaving-voice-channel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain cases where the voice client can get into a bad state and think that you're not connected when you are. Try using the `force` argument for [`VoiceClient.disconnect`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.disconnect) and setting it to `True` when you disconnect.

Comment: Now my bots just disconnects from the voice channel when i type leave in the chat. Thank you so much!